# Foal Ts and Nuxt js

Tags: typescript, rest, api, axios, nuxt.js

i'm using "foal ts" in the backend and i set my endpoints properly , so i can authenticate and get a token for my "Nuxt js " app in the frontend 
i test it with postman and everything perfect 
also my "nuxtJS" app authenticate correctly 
but when i try to fetch /api/note like i did in postman , i got bad request ,

[image]

[image]
// in nuxt component mounted method :

```
this.$axios.get('/api/notes',{data:{email:'admin@gmail.com'}})
.then(res => {return res.data})
.catch(err => {return err.message})
```

what's wrong ???!!!! 
some screenshots from the backend ===>>>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't send a body with a get request usually you would have to send them as query params.